# Is it possible to subclass DataFrame in Pyspark?

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, apache-spark, pyspark

The documentation for Pyspark shows DataFrames being constructed from `sqlContext`, `sqlContext.read()`, and a variety of other methods.

(See https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html)

Is it possible to subclass Dataframe and instantiate it independently? I would like to add methods and functionality to the base DataFrame class.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It really depends on your goals.

- Technically speaking it is possible. `pyspark.sql.DataFrame` is just a plain Python class. You can extend it or monkey-patch if you need.

  ```
  from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

  class DataFrameWithZipWithIndex(DataFrame):
       def __init__(self, df):
           super(self.__class__, self).__init__(df._jdf, df.sql_ctx)

       def zipWithIndex(self):
           return (self.rdd
               .zipWithIndex()
               .map(lambda row: (row[1], ) + row[0])
               .toDF(["_idx"] + self.columns))
  ```

  Example usage:

  ```
  df = sc.parallelize([("a", 1)]).toDF(["foo", "bar"])

  with_zipwithindex = DataFrameWithZipWithIndex(df)

  isinstance(with_zipwithindex, DataFrame)
  ```

  ```
  True
  ```

  ```py
  with_zipwithindex.zipWithIndex().show()
  ```

  ```
  +----+---+---+
  |_idx|foo|bar|
  +----+---+---+
  |   0|  a|  1|
  +----+---+---+
  ```
- Practically speaking you won't be able to do much here. `DataFrame` is an thin wrapper around JVM object and doesn't do much beyond providing docstrings, converting arguments to the form required natively, calling JVM methods, and wrapping the results using Python adapters if necessary.

  With plain Python code you won't be able to even go near `DataFrame` / `Dataset` internals or modify its core behavior. If you're looking for standalone, Python only Spark `DataFrame` implementation it is not possible.