# Extending pyspark's DataFrame class

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to write a custom dataframe object- `CustomFrame` that inherits from the `DataFrame` class of pyspark. This is how it looks like

```
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

class CustomFrame(DataFrame):
        def __init__(self, spark_df, is_vector=False):
            self.is_vector = is_vector

df = CustomFrame(spark.createDataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]], ['a', 'b']))
```

But when I run the following, 
    df.show(1)

I get a recursion error

`RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`

I am not sure what's causing this. I haven't really made any changes to its behavior. Any idea why I am getting this error?

Comment: I guess the 'DataFrame' part of your CustomFrame isn't initiallized properly. You don't actually have a DataFrame currently, you only have a wrapper class. Why not just set an attribute `is_vector` on the regular dataframe? You can use getattr to get the result later (to avoid exceptions).

Comment: @Hitobat, I didnt quite get what you are saying by `...the 'DataFrame' part of your CustomFrame isn't initiallized properly`. Can you elaborate?

Comment: This might help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41598383/is-it-possible-to-subclass-dataframe-in-pyspark

Comment: Good link Suresh.