# How to correctly subclass Pyspark DataFrame class by inheritance? Pyspark warns that calling __init__ via super() is not supported

Tags: python, dataframe, inheritance, pyspark, subclass

I would like to create a class that directly inherits Pyspark's DataFrame, instead of simply containing a DataFrame as an attribute:

```py
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame


# Desired
class ADataFrame(DataFrame):
    ...


# Not Desired
class NotADataFrame:
    def __init__(self, df: DataFrame):
        self.df = df
        ...
    ...
```

The accepted answer to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41598383/is-it-possible-to-subclass-dataframe-in-pyspark), as well as the accepted answer (though not the one with the most upvotes) to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59651935/how-to-add-custom-method-to-pyspark-dataframe-class-by-inheritance) were both great starting points, and led me to this code:

```py
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame


class CustomDataFrame(DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, df: DataFrame) -> None:
        super().__init__(df._jdf, df.sql_ctx)
        ...
    ...
```

This runs without error (for now), but Pyspark warns me that I'm doing something that is not supported and may break in the future:

```
UserWarning: DataFrame.sql_ctx is an internal property, and will be removed in future releases. Use DataFrame.sparkSession instead.

UserWarning: DataFrame constructor is internal. Do not directly use it.
```

I've looked at the [source code](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/dataframe.html) for DataFrame's `__init__`, and I can see where the error is coming from, but I don't understand how I'm supposed to use DataFrame.sparkSession instead, like the warning and the source code is instructing me to, when I'm trying to subclass.

**Is there a correct/supported way to create a subclass of Pyspark's DataFrame class?**

In the question I linked above, the answer with the most upvotes (not the accepted answer) describes a complex method with multiple decorators to add attributes to any class. Is that going to be my best bet?

Any insight would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved after another, more careful read through of the source code.

I just needed to change the line with super() from:

```py
super().__init__(df._jdf, df.sql_ctx)
```

to:

```py
super().__init__(df._jdf, df.sparkSession)
```